# Dictionary matching dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking for matches between which CoinBuy Quote and CoinSell Quote.

I've been able to count instances and when one or more of them appear 6 times I know I have a match across all 6 options. Which is great.

But when I'm struggling to pair up 'CoinBuy's with 'CoinSell's

```
all_options = [
    {'CoinBuy': 1, 'Base': 'DEXE', 'Quote': {'USDT', 'ETH', 'BUSD'}}, 
    {'CoinBuy': 2, 'Base': 'BOND', 'Quote': {'USDT', 'BTC', 'BUSD'}}, 
    {'CoinBuy': 3, 'Base': 'STX', 'Quote': {'USDT', 'BTC', 'BUSD'}}, 
    {'CoinSell': 1, 'Base': 'NAS', 'Quote': {'ETH', 'BTC'}}, 
    {'CoinSell': 2, 'Base': 'CHESS', 'Quote': {'USDT', 'BTC', 'BUSD'}}, 
    {'CoinSell': 3, 'Base': 'REP', 'Quote': {'USDT', 'ETH', 'BTC', 'BUSD'}}
]
```

Expected outcome:

```
Matches
CoinBuy 1 & CoinSell 3  in common 'ETH'

CoinBuy 2 & CoinSell 2  in common 'USDT', 'BTC', 'BUSD'
CoinBuy 3 & CoinSell 1  in common 'BTC', 'BUSD'
```

Comment: Are you looking for matches between specific pairs only?  For example, do you care that CoinBuy 1 & CoinSell 2 -> USDT, BUSD?

Comment: You can use set intersection to look for common elements in the `Quote`.

Comment: no they can match with any combination

Comment: Then why isn't that pair in your expected output?

Comment: Make a list of all the buys, another list of all the sells. Then use a nested loop to compare each buy with each sell. If there are any quotes in common, print the match.

Comment: I've used intersection for other parts of my project but just comparing 2 lists, well 2 sets.  Would it be possible to loop through and these dictionaries?

Comment: don't ask `Would it be possible?`, do it. we're here to help if it fails

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible:

```
dx = dict()
for opt in all_options:
    for quote in opt.get('Quote'):
        ls = dx.get(quote, [])
        ls.append(opt)
        dx[quote] = ls

commonalities = {}

for exchange, opts in dx.items():
    for i in range(len(opts)):
        left = opts[i]
        for j in range(i+1,len(opts)):
            right = opts[j]
            buy_index = sell_index = None
            if 'CoinBuy' in left and 'CoinSell' in right:
                buy_index = left.get('CoinBuy')
                sell_index = right.get('CoinSell')
            elif 'CoinBuy' in right and 'CoinSell' in left:
                buy_index = right.get('CoinBuy')
                sell_index = left.get('CoinSell')
            # Both other cases are invalid pairs
            if buy_index and sell_index:
                commonality = commonalities.get((buy_index, sell_index), [])
                commonality.append(exchange)
                commonalities[(buy_index, sell_index)] = commonality
                
for commonality, exchanges in commonalities.items():
    buy_index, sell_index = commonality
    excs = ", ".join((f"'{e}'" for e in exchanges))
    print(f"CoinBuy {buy_index} & CoinSell {sell_index}  in common {excs}")
```

That said, the above is pretty awkward, and rather brute-force. The basic algorithm is:

- Flip your data structure to create a dictionary that uses the exchange as a key and your options as values. This way you know for each exchange which options pertain.
- For each exchange, painfully construct pairings between options if each side of the pair have opposite types (buy vs sell).
- Flip the indexing again by outputting the pairing indexes as the key and appending each exchange with that same key.
- Walk through the list of pairing indexes and print out all the matching exchanges.

The output looks like:

```
>>> for commonality, exchanges in commonalities.items():
...     buy_index, sell_index = commonality
...     excs = ", ".join((f"'{e}'" for e in exchanges))
...     print(f"CoinBuy {buy_index} & CoinSell {sell_index}  in common {excs}")
... 
CoinBuy 1 & CoinSell 2  in common 'USDT', 'BUSD'
CoinBuy 1 & CoinSell 3  in common 'USDT', 'BUSD', 'ETH'
CoinBuy 2 & CoinSell 2  in common 'USDT', 'BUSD', 'BTC'
CoinBuy 2 & CoinSell 3  in common 'USDT', 'BUSD', 'BTC'
CoinBuy 3 & CoinSell 2  in common 'USDT', 'BUSD', 'BTC'
CoinBuy 3 & CoinSell 3  in common 'USDT', 'BUSD', 'BTC'
CoinBuy 1 & CoinSell 1  in common 'ETH'
CoinBuy 2 & CoinSell 1  in common 'BTC'
CoinBuy 3 & CoinSell 1  in common 'BTC'
```

The only reason I laid this out rather than (more appropriately) let you take a stab at it first is that the intuition to flip the indexing is not common, but it can make this sort of processing a lot easier. Further, it demonstrates how awkward your original datastructure is (why is 'CoinBuy' and 'CoinSell' keys rather than values of another key, say, 'transaction_type'?) and how much additional logic it ends up forcing on you.

Nevertheless, this solution will be unlikely to hold up under a lot of comparisons (consider the number of nested loops). You're probably going to want to think about how you want to convert your original datastructure to something that more easily answers the question you're looking for. Or put this all in a database and use the appropriate query.